# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when trying to use Delete

Tags: node.js, express

trying to make a API where we can use the CRUD options. The thing is our delete function dosnt work at all, when we click delete post the site crashes.

(fill out information cause stackoverflow wont let me post this dumb thing.)

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var express = require('express');
    var cors = require('cors');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');


     mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/shop");


    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    var productSchema = new Schema({
      id: String,
      name: String,
      description: String,
      origin: String,
      categories: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Category"}]
    }, {collection: 'product'});

    var categorySchema = new Schema({
     _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      name: String,
      description: String,
      products: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Product"}]
    }, {collection: 'category'});

    var personSchema = new Schema({
        _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         name: String,
         email: String,
         phone: String
       }, {collection: 'person'});

       var listSchema = new Schema({
        _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         name: String,
         date: String,
         product: [String]
       }, {collection: 'list'});

    var Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
    var Category = mongoose.model('Category', categorySchema);
    var Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);
    var List = mongoose.model('List', listSchema);


    var app = express();
    app.use(cors());
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

    /* Get */

    app.get('/', function(req,res){
        Product.find({}, '', function(error, product){
            Person.find({},'', function(error, person){
                Category.find({},'', function(error, category){
                    List.find({},'', function(error, list){
                        res.json({
                            Product: product,
                            Person: person,
                            Category: category,
                            List: list
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });



    app.post("/product", function(req, res) {
        var newItem = new Product (req.body);
        newItem.save()
            .then (function(product) {
                Category.findByIdAndUpdate(
                req.body.categories, { $push: {"products": product._id }}, { new: true }, function (err, product) {
                    res.send(product);
            })
            .catch (function(err) {
                res.status(400).send("unable to add item to db");
            });
        });
    });



    app.get('/all', function(req,res){
        Category.
            find({}).
            populate("products").
            exec(function (err, product) {
                res.json(product);
            });
    });

    app.get('/category/:id', function(req,res){
        Category.
            find({_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)}).
            populate("products").
            exec(function (err, product) {
                res.json(product);
            });
    });

    app.get('/category/1', function(req,res){
        Category.
            find({name: "grönsaker"}).
            populate("products").
            exec(function (err, product) {
                res.json(product);
            });
    });

    app.get('/category/2', function(req,res){
        Category.
            find({name: "mejeri"}).
            populate("products").
            exec(function (err, product) {
                res.json(product);
            });
    });










    app.put('/product/:id', function(req, res)  {
        Product.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, { $set: req.body }, { new: true }, function (err, product) {
            if (err) return handleError(err);
            res.send(product);
          });
    });

    /

    app.delete('/product', function (req, res) {
        Category.findById(req.body._id, function (err, product) {
            var cat_id = Product.categories [0]
            Category.findByIdAndUpdate(cat_id, { $pull: {products: req.body._id}}, function(err, product){
                product.remove();
            });
        });
    });

    app.listen(3000);
```

We know that the SendDeleteRequest is wrong with the ID but we don't know what we should write instead.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Express.js client</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>

        function sendGetRequest() {
        var data = { id: 123 };
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:3000/all",
            type: "GET",
            data: data,
            success: response => $("#response").text(JSON.stringify(response))
        }); 
        }

        function sendGetGronsaker() {
        var data = { id: "5a1696d69759edba95fa4b18" };
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:3000/category/5a1696d69759edba95fa4b18",
            type: "GET",
            data: data,
            success: response => $("#response").text(JSON.stringify(response))
        }); 
        }

        function sendGetMejeri() {
        var data = { id: "5a1696d69759edba95fa4b17" };
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:3000/category/5a1696d69759edba95fa4b17",
            type: "GET",
            data: data,
            success: response => $("#response").text(JSON.stringify(response))
        }); 
        }

        /* function sendGetGronsaker() {
        var data = { id: "5a1696d69759edba95fa4b18" };
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:3000/category/5a1696d69759edba95fa4b18",
            type: "GET",
            data: data,
            success: response => $("#response").text(JSON.stringify(response))
        }); 
        } */

        function sendPostRequest() {
            var data = { name: "majs", description: "Majs är gott", origin: "spain", categories: "5a1696d69759edba95fa4b18" };
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:3000/product",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: response => $("#response").text(JSON.stringify(response))
            }); 
        }

        function sendPutRequest() { 
            var data = { origin: "spain" };
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:3000/product/5a1696d79759edba95fa4b20",
                type: "PUT",
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: response => $("#response").text(JSON.stringify(response))
            }); 
        }

        function sendDeleteRequest() {
            var data = { id: 789 };
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:3000/product",
                type: "DELETE",
                data: data,
                success: response => $("#response").text(response)
            }); 
        }
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
        #output {
            margin-bottom: 3ex;
        }

        #label {
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="output">
            <span id="label">Server response:</span>
            <span id="response"></span>
        </div>

        <div>
            <button onclick="sendGetMejeri()">GET Mejeri</button>
            <button onclick="sendGetGronsaker()">GET Gronsaker</button>
            <button onclick="sendGetRequest()">GET All</button>
            <button onclick="sendPostRequest()">Send POST request</button>
            <button onclick="sendPutRequest()">Send tomat PUT request</button>
            <button onclick="sendDeleteRequest()">Send DELETE request</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing id parameter without underscore char

Just change req.body.**_id** to req.body.**id**

```
app.delete('/product', function (req, res) {
    Category.findById(req.body.id, function (err, product) {
        var cat_id = Product.categories [0]
        Category.findByIdAndUpdate(cat_id, { $pull: {products: req.body.id}}, function(err, product){
            product.remove();
        });
    });
});
```